# Make Visual Studio remember my login and password

Tags: visual-studio-2010, credentials

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with source control (TFS). Each time I open new instance of Visual Studio and connect to Team Explorer, it asks me for my credentials. I'm already logged in to Windows with the same domain user.

Is there a way to make Visual Studio remember my credentials, so I don't have to type them every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Team Explorer under VS2010 authenticates to Team Foundation Server using the Windows authentication.

So you ca try to add your credentials under Credential Manager (Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager).